# Android App Stops Working - Database Information Not Submitting Correctly?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-activity

So i'm dipping my hand into android development and have started with making a phonebook app
My app has a few activities - A main activity, a add contact activity and a view all activity.

Currently whenever I try to add a contact and press save the android app stops working which I believe is because empty values are ending up in the database or the wrong information is being entered to the database

Just wondering if anyone could have a little look over and see if they can spot anything im missing.

I think the problem is on this activity from line 33 as the TOAST message does not appear it just crashes as soon as the save data button is pressed

```
package uk.ac.northumbria.securephonebook;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
* Created by Michael on 10/03/2017.
*/

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBHELPER";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact";
public static final String FIELD_ID = "_id";
public static final String FIELD_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
public static final String FIELD_SURNAME = "surname";
public static final String FIELD_TELEPHONE = "telephone";
public static final String FIELD_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String QUERY_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+FIELD_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+FIELD_FIRSTNAME+" VARCHAR (100),"+FIELD_SURNAME+" VARCHAR (100), "+FIELD_TELEPHONE+" VARCHAR (100), "+FIELD_EMAIL+" VARCHAR (100)";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL (QUERY_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

After fixing the issues of the button the below is now generated
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contacts (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(email,surname,firstname,telephone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: can you post the crash log.

Comment: Added the Crash Log as requested

Comment: There is an SQLException when creating the table indicated in the crash log. Post the database.java code

Comment: Added the Database.java and the DPHelper which holds the SQL Create Query

Comment: The exception happens when you create the table. Your database class does not contain the code for creating the table. Post the correct code and  stop posting your code as images. Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Apologies, i'm fairly new and didn't realise the website could embed  - Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

The QUERY_CREATE is missing a ')' at the end.

Change this

```
 public static final String QUERY_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+FIELD_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+FIELD_FIRSTNAME+" VARCHAR (100),"+FIELD_SURNAME+" VARCHAR (100), "+FIELD_TELEPHONE+" VARCHAR (100), "+FIELD_EMAIL+" VARCHAR (100)";
```

to

```
 public static final String QUERY_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ( "+FIELD_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+FIELD_FIRSTNAME+" VARCHAR (100),"+FIELD_SURNAME+" VARCHAR (100), "+FIELD_TELEPHONE+" VARCHAR (100), "+FIELD_EMAIL+" VARCHAR (100) )";
```

Comment: Thank You for your patience  - That fixed it - Cannot believe it was something so minor that I had missed

Comment: Happy to help! If the answer helped you can you upvote and mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Under 15 Rep so it won't allow me yet but ill save this and ensure I send you the REP when I can.

I don't suppose you can work out why this now happens: